# I get an error when running ffmpeg in a daemonized process

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm running ffmpeg(4.3.1) in a python(3.7.7) file using the `subprocess.call()` function.

```py
cmd = f'ffmpeg -y -i "{mv_temp_out_path}" -vcodec h264 "{mv_ffmpeg_path}"'
# cmd = f'ffmpeg -y -i "{mv_temp_out_path}" -vcodec h264_nvenc "{mv_ffmpeg_path}"' # gpu
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

However, when running the python file in gunicorn, I get an error when running it with the `-D option` (daemonization). If I run it without the `-D` option, it works fine.I'm wondering if I can't use gpu and I get the same error when I set it to use cpu.

The result is as follows.

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './Outputs/TempSaveMovie/200703_4_short_5fr_p2(100_20)_r(50_20).mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10246 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 10244 kb/s, 13 fps, 13 tbr, 13312 tbn, 13 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec17c5480] header damaged
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec17c6840] header damaged
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec1855f80] header damaged
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec1866e00] header damaged
Output #0, mp4, to './Outputs/MovieOutputs/200703_4_short_5fr_p2(100_20)_r(50_20).mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 2000 kb/s, 13 fps, 13312 tbn, 13 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 h264_nvenc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/2000000 buffer size: 4000000 vbv_delay: N/A
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec17c8780] header damaged
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec17c5480] header damaged
...
...
...
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec1855f80] header damaged
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec1866e00] header damaged
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
    Last message repeated 3 times
frame=   83 fps=0.0 q=14.0 Lsize=    1800kB time=00:00:06.30 bitrate=2337.4kbits/s dup=76 drop=0 speed=18.7x
video:1799kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.064613%
Conversion failed!
```

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me about this. Thank you in advance.

*Postscript*
I modified the code as follows and ran it.

```
com = ['/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', '/var/www/System/Backend/Outputs/TempSaveMovie/200703_4.mp4', '-vcodec', 'h264_nvenc', '/var/www/System/Backend/Outputs/MovieOutputs/200703_4.mp4']
subprocess.call(com, shell=False)
```

The result is as follows.

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --disable-shared --enable-static
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
"/var/www/System/Backend/Outputs/TempSaveMovie/200703_4.mp4": No such file or directory
1
```

```
os.path.exists('/var/www/System/Backend/Outputs/TempSaveMovie/200703_4.mp4')
=> True
```

Comment: The error message shows `/var/www/20006_NDIS/` while you are testing whether the same path without `20006_NDIS` exists.

Comment: It was the name of a file in a directory I wanted to hide and I wanted to delete it, but I forgot about it.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)
```

To hide Cmd window

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I've modified the code as described in the postscript and ran it.

I got a warning that the file does not exist. Sorry I don't know much about the subprocess function.

Comment: I fixed the code, I tried running it with shell = False, but I still get the same error.